# Kendo dataSource.add - "Id is not defined"

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to add some items to a Kendo DataSource to then display in the grid. However, every time I try to save I get `Reference Error: Id is not defined`.

At first I thought it was because I didn't include `Id` in my schema but I checked and it looks alright.

```
var viewModel = new kendo.observable({
orgDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/Organization/GetAll",
            dataType: "json"
        },
        update: {
            url: "/Host/Organization/Edit",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: getAntiForgeryToken()
            }
        },
        create: {
            url: "/Host/Organization/Create",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: getAntiForgeryToken()
            }
        },
        destroy: {
            url: "/Host/Organization/Delete",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: getAntiForgeryToken()
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: true },
                Name: { type: "string" },
                LicenseExpiration: { type: "date" },
                LicenseNumber: { type: "number" },
                Active: { type: "boolean" },
                CreateDate: { type: "date" },
                LastModDate: { type: "date" },
                AvailableLicenses: { type: "string" },
                State: { type: "string" }
            }
        },
        errors: "errorMsg"
    },
    pageSize: 20,
    error: function (e) {
        toastr.options = {
            "positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width"
        };
        toastr.error("There was an error: " + e.errors, "Uh, Oh!");
        this.cancelChanges();
    },
    serverPaging: false,
    serverFiltering: false,
    serverSorting: false
}),
reloadOrganizations: function () {
    this.get("orgDataSource").read();
},
onOrgSave: function (e)
{
    var uid = $('input[name="OrgRowUID"]').val();
    var tr = $('tr[data-uid="' + uid + '"]'); // get the current table row (tr)
    var name = $('input[name="Name"]').val();
    var licenseNumber = $('input[name="LicenseNumber"]').val();
    var licenseExpiration = $('input[name="LicenseExpiration"]').val();
    var email = $('input[name="Email"]').val();
    var state = $('input[name="State"]').val();
    var logo = $('input[name="ImageUrl]').val();
    var active = $('input[name="Active"]').is(":checked");

    // get the data bound to the current table row
    var orgGrid = $("#OrganizationGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = orgGrid.dataItem(tr);

    if (data == null)
    {
        viewModel.orgDataSource.add({ Name: name, LicenseNumber: licenseNumber, LicenseExpiration: licenseExpiration, Email: email, State: state, ImageUrl: logo, Active: active })
        orgGrid.saveChanges();
        viewModel.orgDataSource.sync();
        viewModel.reloadOrganizations();
    } else {
        data.set("Name", name);
        data.set("LicenseNumber", licenseNumber);
        data.set("LicenseExpiration", licenseExpiration);
        data.set("Email", email);
        data.set("State", state);
        data.set("ImageUrl", logo);
        data.set("Active", active);
    }

    $("#orgCreateModal").modal('hide');
    $("#orgEditModal").modal('hide');
}
});
```

The error is occurring on this line:

```
viewModel.orgDataSource.add({ Name: name, LicenseNumber: licenseNumber, LicenseExpiration: licenseExpiration, Email: email, State: state, ImageUrl: logo, Active: active });
```

The error in FireBug is:

> Reference Error: Id is not defined - kendo.all.min.js line 25 > function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's throwing that error because you're not setting "Id" to anything in your datasource.  I had a similar problem a while back and Telerik said you have to give 'id' a valid unique value because they use that internally to keep things straight in the datasource.  In your case, you are setting your schema id to "Id", but it doesn't look like your datasource has an "Id" field.  I ended up just dumping a guid in there and it fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks @Ageonix, that makes sense. I'll give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: Did you have any luck?